# How to make a JS If Then statement for a checkbox with numeric value?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am trying to create a basic pricing calculator for my website so that the customers can get a basic estimate of the cost. For part of the pricing I am trying to make checkboxes, where if they are selected, it adds for example 100 to the total. However if it isn't selected, the nothing is added to the total. I've been trying to use the code below but I'm definitely not doing something right. Thank you in advance for the help. I'm brand new to the JS and HTML world so I appreciate the help!

I have included my current javascript below. I'm hoping to have Number 1 and Number 2 be text boxes and Number 3 be a check box.

```
var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {

var num1 = document.getElementById('Number1').value;

var num2 = document.getElementById('Number2').value;

var num3 = if (document.getElementById('Number3').value == 1) 
{ 
document.getElementById('Number3').value = '100'; 
} 
else if (document.getElementById('Number3').value == 0) 
{ 
value = '0'; 
} ;

var answer = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2) + parseInt(num3);

document.getElementById('Answer').innerHTML = answer;



}, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your JS. The first one comes from:

```
var num3 = if (document.getElementById('Number3').value == 1) 
{ 
    document.getElementById('Number3').value = '100'; 
} 
else if (document.getElementById('Number3').value == 0) 
{ 
    value = '0'; 
} ;
```

This is a syntax error. You could instead use the ternary operator:

```
var num3 = document.getElementById('Number3').checked ? 100 : 0;
// condition ? value to return if true : value to return if false
```

You also need to check that the value of your inputs are not `undefined` and assign them a default value:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById('Number1').value || 0;
var num2 = document.getElementById('Number2').value || 0;
```

See working example:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById('Number1').value || 0;
  var num2 = document.getElementById('Number2').value || 0;
  var num3 = document.getElementById('Number3').checked ? 100 : 0;

  var answer = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2) + num3;

  document.getElementById('Answer').innerHTML = answer;
}, true);
```

```html
<input id="Number1"/>
<input id="Number2"/>
<input id="Number3" type="checkbox"/>
<button id="submitButton">Go</button>
<div id="Answer"></div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and your instructions were great. Thank you very much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var num3 = if (document.getElementById('Number3').value == 1)
```

use:

```
if(document.getElementById("Number3").checked){
//add the values here 
}
```

Hope this helps